# Javascript .match regular expression with reverse quantifier (or parse right to left)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, reverse

Given a string like such...

```
"ABCDEFG"
```

Is it possible to have a quantifier that works in "reverse" so to say?

**For instance:**

```
var foo = "ABCDEFG";
foo.match(/.{1,3}/g);
```

Results in:

```
// Array(3) ["ABC", "DEF", "G"]
```

**What I'm trying achieve:**

```
// Array(3) ["A", "BCD", "EFG"]
```

So regardless of the string length, the array is always a representation of the string, with each node 3 characters in length (except possibly the 1st) but always starting at the end of the string.  So the first array item might be 1, 2 or 3 characters long, simply depending on what's "left over".

**I have tried using the following to error:**

```
foo.match(/.{-1,3}/g); // null
foo.match(/.{1,-3}/g); // null
```

Thinking perhaps I could use negatives similar to splitting strings, however each of those examples returns null.

I'm assuming this can be done within the pattern somehow and not the quantifier, so I'd like to understand how that would be written with `.match()`.  Or would this require having to write a custom method that would involve other string manipulation in order to accomplish this?

Comment: This `.{3}|.{2}|.` or `...|..|.`? Otherwise what @WiktorStribiżew says below

Comment: You can `reverse()` a string and run your regex on it, then `reverse()` the results. No quantifier will be able to do what you ask for since the string is parsed from left to right.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew That's what I was starting to figure out.  Was mostly wondering if there's a way to modify the pattern to parse right to left without running reverse() or other operations.

Comment: @RobertWade not in JavaScript. Other languages like C# provide a flag that allows you to run regex rtl instead of ltr, but that's not available in many languages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Regular expressions always match from left to right, but you can use a positive lookahead with an end-of-string anchor to achieve what you want:

```
var foo = "ABCDEFG";
foo.match(/.{1,3}(?=(.{3})*$)/g);  // ["A", "BCD", "EFG"]
```

Here the subpattern `(?=(.{3})*$)` is a lookahead expression that matches zero or more repetitions of (exactly!) 3 characters, bounded at the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: I was thinking the same and have just missed the point by not including the $ into the lookahead, great to know that this could be done with a regex.

Comment: A brilliant solution!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments there's no regex or quantifier that matches your string from backwards reading from right to left.

What you can do here is to reverse the `string` before calling `.match()` then reverse the matches `array`:

```
var matches = foo.split("").reverse().join("")
    .match(/.{1,3}/g).map(m => m.split("").reverse().join(""))
    .reverse();
```

**Explanation:**

- We use `foo.split("").reverse().join("")` to reverse the original `string`.
- Then call `.match()` with this reversed `string`.
- Reverese the matches with `.map(m => m.split("").reverse().join(""))`.
- And finally reverse the matches `array`.

**Demo:**

```js
var foo = "ABCDEFG";

var matches = foo.split("").reverse().join("").match(/.{1,3}/g).map(m => m.split("").reverse().join("")).reverse();
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: You need to reverse strings as well, because you've reversed only the array of matches, so you need to the reverse the matches themselves as well

Comment: @user10089632 well pointed out, thank you, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct a custom regex, you can use that to pull out the matches in the right order:

```
var foo = "ABCDEFG";
console.log(foo.match(new RegExp("(.{"+foo.length % 3+"})"+"(...)".repeat(Math.floor(foo.length / 3)))));
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tested this however and it yields: `["ABC", "DEF", "G"]` which is no different than the original `foo.match(/.{1,3}/g);`.  https://jsfiddle.net/bzkzust7/